# Program fails when input is 10 and factorial value is returning upto 33 number only

Tags: c, factorial

When **10** is entered as input the program (for calculating factorials) fails, whereas for all other inputs (within system limits) the program works fine except when any character is entered it goes into infinite loop with output as "Factorial of 1 is 1".

If I enter 34 or any number greater than 34 then I am getting output as "factorial of [entered number] is 0". Why the factorial value is 0 for number greater than 33?

Here is the program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

int display();
void fact_fun(int num_fact);

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    char next;

    next=display();

    while( next != '\n')
    {
        num = next;
        fact_fun(num);
        next=display();
    }

    return 0;
}

int display()
{
    int input;
    printf("\nEnter number to find factorial or press ENTER to exit :");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    return input;
}

void fact_fun(int num_fact)
{
    int fact=1;
    if((num_fact>='a' && num_fact<='z') || (num_fact>='A' && num_fact<='Z'))
    {
        printf("Alphabet is not allowed");
    }
    else if(num_fact < 0)
    {
        printf("Negative number is not allowed");
    }
    else if(num_fact == 0)
    {
        printf("Factorial of %d is 1",num_fact);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<= num_fact; i++)
        {
            fact = fact*i;
        }
        printf("Factorial of %d is %d",num_fact,fact);
    }
}
```

Kindly guide me where I am making mistake.

Comment: `34!` is `295232799039604140847618609643520000000`. What's the largest value that can be stored in an `int` on your machine? Is it smaller or larger than `295232799039604140847618609643520000000`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson My system is 64-bit so it can hold integer values in the range of at least 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: @user3121023 Then what should be done if accepting integer and character in one variable?

Comment: @VasudhaDixit, 64 bit system only allows for that much storage. But the `Int32` stays 32 bit. Try looking into `long`

Comment: @Kari: `long` is only guaranteed to represent +/-(2**31-1) either (whatever `Int32` is, it's not a standard type). And this does not depend on the platform, but the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `display` function you are using `char` instead of `int` as you are using `%d` format specifier in `scanf`, change it to `int` everywhere. You must have seen the warning while compiling:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
```

Apart from this, your program fails to deliver when number entered is **10**, to solve it:

```
 while(next>=0) //WHEN NEGATIVE NUMBER IS ENTERED IT WILL END THE LOOP
 {
    num = next;
    fact_fun(num);
    next=display();
 }
```

Simplify the **fact_fun:**

```
void fact_fun(int num_fact)
{
    int fact =1;
    if(num_fact == 0)
    {
        printf("Factorial of %d is 1",num_fact);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<= num_fact; i++)
        {
            fact = fact*i;
        }
        printf("Factorial of %d is %d",num_fact,fact);
    }
}
```

Then it will work fine.

**REASON BEHIND FAILURE OF PROGRAM WHEN INPUT IS 10:** The `ASCII` value of newline `\n` is also **10**, so when ten is entered, the `int` value of `\n` is compared to value returned by `display` i.e. **10**, hence the while loop is never executed in this case.

Here is how a safe method of taking input should be (`scanf` is a disaster):

```
int display()
{
    char inp[10]={0};
    int  input;
    int index=0;
    printf("Enter number to find factorial or press ENTER to exit : ");

    while(((input=getchar())!=EOF)&(index<10))
    {
        if((input>='0')&&(input<='9'))
        {
            inp[index++]=input;
        }
        else if(input=='\n')
            break;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    input=atoi(inp);

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the program is not failing at input 10. But I don't understand why it not working with `while( next != '\n')` ?

Comment: @VasudhaDixit Updated my answer.

Comment: As input is stored in one variable(it is of int type) and if I enter character then it will go into infinite loop then what can be done to resolve it ?

Comment: @VasudhaDixit Updated

Comment: But the program is going into infinite loop when entered alphabet or symbol character

Comment: @VasudhaDixit You need change the way you are taking input in`display` function for that, updated the answer.